# Is there a rigorous definition of ‘everything’?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-language

Is there a rigorous definition for this concept? ‘The collection of every individual thing’? If an ‘individual thing’ is something that is different from something else, ‘everything’ could be the collection of every x that is not y where x≠y?

Comment: But every "thing" satisfies the formula **∀x(x=x)**.

Comment: The collection of **x** such that **∃y (x≠y)** ? And if the world is made of one only thing ? See [Monism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism).

Comment: If you are taking anything "in its broadest sense" you are admitting exactly the kind of looseness that rules out its "rigorous definition", it is called being future open. But look at [Williamson's paper Everything](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3840881). Do "individual electrons" satisfy x=x? I don't know, they are indistinguishable, after all, see [SEP's Individuality in Quantum Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-idind/). Does a river? Not according to Heraclitus.

Comment: @Conifold I eliminated that expression, thanks - also for the links, I’ll read them. I’d say that excepted the one electron universe theory, individual electrons are not identical, since they occupy different positions

Comment: You are thinking of electrons as classical particles, that doesn't work. They do not "occupy" any positions, the wave function of even a single electron is smeared all over the universe, and "position" is an operator that can not be used to individuate.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for your proposal; if the world is made of only one thing there’s nothing different from it and it has no relations and characteristics - so it is not a good thing. Moreover, letters are all the same and you can’t read this comment.

Comment: @Conifold I’d say values instead of positions? Anyway you are referring to the one electron universe theory, sadly I’ve not the instruments to evaluate it.

Comment: Values, positions, one electron, many, makes little difference, Multi-electron wave function is not even defined on space, and "counting" of electrons is not accomplished by individuating them. "Individual thing" is just a wrong category to describe what there is according to quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Conifold yes, this is why I use ‘thing’ in its broadest sense, where a number, an event, an idea and a probability are things. They have an identity due their differences from other things.

Comment: everything = the orthocomplement of nothing ?

Comment: Verbal games will not help, "thing in the broadest sense" is still too classical if you want identity conditions. You'll have to drop your current way of thinking entirely, and come up with a different conceptualization that builds on quantum ontology rather than tries to stretch classical one beyond its usefulness.

Comment: @Conifold I quote the Williamson's paper you suggested, I agree with this: [...] Whatever is is a thing. If there were any non-things, they too would be things: so there are no non-things. In any sense of ‘exist’ in which there are non-existents, they are things just as much as existents are. Any natural or unnatural kind or substance is a thing; so too is any member of the kind or sample of the substance. Whatever is abstract or concrete or neither is a thing. Whatever is basic or derived, simple or complex, is a thing. Whatever can be named is a thing; so too is whatever cannot be named.

Comment: Good, as you can see from the paper Williamson is not exactly in the majority, and since he quantifies over "things" he is thinking of classical ontology, not quantum. "Everything" isn't everything after all, "*however emphatically one utters it and however hard one hammers the table with one’s fist*".

Answer (score 2):

The set *U* of all things:  For all *x*, *x* is an element of *U*.

Unfortunately, *U* can be shown not to exist. Apparently every set must exclude something. (See Russell's Paradox)

Comment: The OP is asking for a definition not about forming a collection by using it. By the way, Russell's Paradox features the set of all *sets*, not of all "things", so it does not include "everything". And there is no problem with forming a class of all sets anyway.

Comment: The category Set includes all sets and does not suffer from Russell's paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I agree with @Conifold by the way

Comment: @Conifold Russell's Paradox features the set of all sets that are not elements of themselves. The set of all sets (if you have an is-a-set predicate) and the set of everything (my example) can both be proven not to exist using ordinary set theory and Russell's Paradox.

Comment: This answer is poor because it assumes the use of a specific axiomatisation of set theory which *has been explicitly constructed to exclude sets which contain themselves*, like the set of all sets. Furthermore, because Russell's paradox does not deal with the set of all sets, by relaxing some of the axioms of ZFC (like the misleadingly named notion of "well-foundedness"), the set of all sets can be easily constructed by taking the union of all sets.

Comment: @CarlMasens There is no need to invoke any axioms of set theory that exclude sets which contain themselves in order to handle these paradoxes. The only axiom of set theory we need is one that enables us to obtain arbitrary subsets from other sets. The rules of predicate logic can handle the rest.

Comment: If there is the set of all sets restricted comprehension of ZFC makes the set of all sets not elements of themselves into its subset, so the Russell's paradox applies to both. But I do not see any relevance of it,  predicates ("definitions")  need not determine sets, "everything" in ZFC is a set so already the setting of your example makes it moot, and NBG allows one to form the class of all sets if one so wishes.

Comment: @Conifold If everything is considered to be a set (as in ZFC), then the of set of all sets is just the set of everything. Otherwise, the set of all sets could be different from the set of everything. And when I say "ordinary set theory," I exclude any kind of class theory like NBG. I think most people would.

Comment: You still do not see how everything you said in the last two comments is moot to the OP?

Comment: @Conifold No. In what way would the set U as I have defined it not be the set of everything (if it existed)? What would be excluded?

Comment: First, you conflate OP's "things" with no relation to set theory (and apparently meant as real things) with "things" in set theory (which are not even real unless one is a platonist). Then you make a remark about non-existence of a set, which would have been irrelevant to the question even if the OP did identify "things" with sets. What is excluded? Everything the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Conifold A set, itself an abstraction, can also contain physical things like dogs, horses, planets or stars. It can also contain other abstractions. It cannot however contain everything. Assuming otherwise leads to a contradiction. Do you disagree?

Comment: Whether I agree or disagree is moot because the question you are asking is moot, the OP does not care about the answer to it.

Comment: @Conifold She should care if it is a serious question.

Comment: This sounds like [no true Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman), which of course is a fallacy. One can care about the definition of linear spaces without (in the same question) caring whether their collection forms a set.

Answer (score 2):

To ask, What does 'everything' consist of? is to ask in effect, What things exist? This is the fundamental question of ontology. There have been many attempts to make this question rigorous by tying ontology to logic. One of the most popular approaches is to say that quantified formulas of the form (∃x)Fx are true if and only if there exists an object in the domain of quantification which when substituted for x satisfies the open formula Fx. Quine summarizes this position with the aphorism: To be is to be the value of a variable. 'Everything' is then the entirety of our domain of quantification.

Of course, this leaves unsettled the question as to what should be in our domain of quantification. We could be minimalist and hold that it should contain only those things that are necessary for a scientific account of the universe, but this places a huge burden on the reductionist program. Who is to say what is absolutely necessary, and for what purpose?

Restricting our logic to first order is perhaps too limiting: we might think it reasonable to quantify over properties or classes or propositions. Do numbers exist? Mathematicians quantify over them, but they don't seem to be the same kind of thing as chairs and kangaroos. Do events exist? Davidson proposed that we quantify over events in order to explain how "John ran quickly" entails "John ran". Do fictional entities exist in some extended sense? Meinong thought so, and free logics permit an extended domain of quantification containing fictional entities. Do minds exist? Or are they reducible to or identical with physical things? Do the fundamental particles of physics really exist? Physicists quantify over them, but pragmatist philosophers hold that they are nothing more than useful fictions that serve to aid us in making predictions. Do possible worlds exist? Many logicians and philosophers of language quantify over possible worlds, but only a few such as David Lewis are willing to allow that they have real existence.

So, even when you think you have found a rigorous criterion, most of the interesting questions about ontology remain.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer! As I use the term, things need not to exist in a specific (like pragmatic) way for being so. A number or a Pegasus can not exist in some sense, but they are still _something_: i.e concepts, mythological fictions etc. To be a thing it’s enough to have any identity, to be different to something else.